# Crop images with irfanview

Tags: csv, batch-file, command, line

I'm using [Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/) that can be run through the command line.
My problem is as follows:

My batch file:

```
i_view 32.exe /filelist=c:\test\*.pcx /crop=(1,2,3,4,5) /convert=c:\temp\*.pcx
```

Where 1 is x axis value, 2 is y axis value, 3 is width, 4 is height and 5 is origin.

I need to batch crop two hundred plus images, but my batch file crops all images to (1,2,3,4,5) specifications whereas i need the values to change depending on which image is being processed.
In other words the first image that gets cropped is going to be 3×4 pixels cropped 1 pixel right and 2 pixels up from origin option 5, but I need the next file in the folder to have different values for all five variables of crop command preferably via a csv table or something.
Does anyone know if this is possible?

Ps- irfanview has closed its forum to registering new accounts

Comment: No offense intended, but you should use the ` (The sign just before the `1` number ) to type a **Code**

Comment: Please share what you have tried!

Comment: @Mr.Helpy, this is true on a US keyboard layout, but not globally...

Comment: @aschipfl Well there are many secondary ideas you can try if you Really care about your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q35953462.txt"
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1-6delims=," %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 ECHO(i_view32 %%a /crop=(%%b,%%c,%%d,%%e,%%f^) /convert=%destdir%\%%~na.pcx
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q35953462.txt` containing some dummy data for my testing.

> file1.pcx,1,2,3,4,5
>   file2.pcx,5,4,3,2,1
>   file3.pcx,2,4,6,8,10

The proposed `i_view32` commands are merely `echo`ed to the screen. To activate **following verification** change `echo(i_view32` to `i_view32`

With the file,

read each line and tokenise using `,` as a delimiter. There are 6 tokens, nominated as `%%a` and inplicitly `%%b`..`%%f`

I don't know the `irfanview` syntax for a single file, so I'll leave the polishing to you.

Note that `)` needs to be escaped `^)` because it is within a code block.

Comment: Alot of this has helped but im still having issues. I have tried your batch and it tells me 1-6delims was unexpected.                                  Also do you put your q35953462.txt in the sourcedir with the frames you wish to crop?   Maybe their is an easier way to do it?

Comment: It would appear that you have retyped the code and made a typo. I cut-and-pasted my code from my test setup. Safest to cut-and-paste. Batch is sensitive to spacing - you can't separate the options onto separate lines, and the quotes must be as-is, not "smart quotes" as used in WP applications. You can put the file wherever you want it - that's why its name is placed in a variable - to make it easier to change rather than chasing all over the routine if you want to change something (this routine is simple - can be a pain with larger ones) Just replace `...q35...` with the filename you require.

Comment: Thanks, I definitely have made a typo or something. I have read and read alot on this but despite my best efforts I can't get any form of for  /f token to work. Sometimes I get 'was unexpected ' message then when I add quotes I get syntax error. Maybe because I am using an old windows xp laptop I cant connect to wifi to cut and paste just yet whereas I read somewhere that userqback is spotty for windows xp!? Maybe my txt file is not formatted correctly?

Comment: I've just used a USB stick to transfer and test on XP. Worked perfectly for me...

Comment: Cheers! It works perfect,thankyou I was losing my mind. My error was that my batch file was saved in UNICODE so resaving in ANSI helped. Also I can use your syntax to my own thankyou so much.I have another question but I am posting it as a new question. It deals with making my txt file from raw data (another txt file) using a batch parser? Thanks again!